# Determining Stability of Fixed points of systems of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have Non Linear Dynamic Systems for which I have computed the fixed points, and now I wish to investigate the nature of these points (primarily whenever they are stable or not). I understand that the way to do so is to compute the Jacobian of the system and then to find its Eigenvalues in the fixed point. If all have real part less than 0 the point is stable, otherwise not.

Now, will looking all this up I found a so called "Poincaré Diagram" on wikipedia
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory). No actual information was given on it and I have not found anything else on it. However, it seemed very useful. Exactly for what systems does this one hold? Can I actually use it for systems with more than 2 variables?

Finally, if I cannot use this so called Poincaré Diagram, is there a good way to determine whenever you have oscillations around a fixed point?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to MSE. We are ready here to help you, but it would be good if you could give us some context:  What exactly is your question? What have you done? Where have you stuck? Further, your question is indeed a chain of questions: "if I cannot use ..., then ...?"  Please look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: If not all the eigenvalues of the linearization of an ODE system at a rest point have negative real parts the rest point can be still asymptotically stable, see the zero rest point for $x'=-x^3$: the (unique) eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: Thank you, clarifying a question would be under what circumstances the so called Poincaré Diagram showed on wikipedia holds.

Comment: A little piece of advice: I don't know what your level of understanding mathematics is, but I suspect that it is such that you should do some **systematic** study before you are able to benefit from reading this Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you, do you have a suggested source which is good for studying this?

Comment: Perhaps Steven Strogatz' [Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos.  With Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry and Engineering](https://books.google.com/books?id=A0paDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=strogatz+nonlinear+dynamics&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn57Pur7LcAhWGPFAKHSN6B1YQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=strogatz%20nonlinear%20dynamics&f=false)?